# Laravel Lumen - Eloquent Query Log

Tags: laravel, lumen

I'm using Laravel Lumen to build an API.

I've come to a point where I need to find out what SQL query is being generated by Eloquent. I know how to do this in Laravel 4 and Laravel 5 but i've tried the same code in Lumen and the query is blank?

```
$queries    = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);

echo 'Query<pre>';
    print_r($last_query);
exit;
```

The above code, when run in Laravel works fine - in Lumen the query is blank?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the query log in Laravel Lumen working you need to enable it:

`DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();`

You can add that code in to your controller, middleware, etc then use:

```
$queries    = DB::getQueryLog();
$lastQuery = end($queries);

dd($lastQuery)
```

To print your query.

You can also use the following with eloquent:

```
$myModel = Users::where('active', true);

dd($myModel->getSql(), $myModel->getBindings());
```

You must run the `getSql()` and `getBindings()` before you call `->first()` or `->get()`, etc

Comment: I'm using Lumen 5.7, and the above code only logs the likes df DB::select etc. Not eloquent model retrieval etc - which I was hoping it would.

Comment: @NigelAtkinson Have you tried `dd($eloquentQuery->toSql(), $eloquentQuery->getBindings());`

Comment: Thanks ajtrichards, those do work, however I figured out the problem. I had LadaCache which caches eloquent queries in redis not quite as disabled as I thought.

Answer (score 5):

Just call this after the query to keep it quick and simple:

```
echo $query->toSql();
```